# Feature selection based on (automatic) multicollinearity detection

Tags: python, feature-selection, multicollinearity

as part of an automatic feature selection pipeline, I am wanting to automatically remove features if they are highly correlated, based on its Variable Inflation Factor (VIF) result. Below is an example of df (although the data I use often have >200 features), vif calculation function, and while loop to continue until all VIF results are less than 100.

The while loop breaks if vif_data['VIF'].iloc[1] is an inf value. In my example, there are a small number of rows with inf values, however, the issue is that there are features below these rows that have VIF values above 100 - the while loop breaks because the first row VIF value is inf and not a number.

```
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4],
     'b': [2, 2, 3, 2, 1],
     'c': [4, 6, 7, 8, 9],
     'd': [4, 3, 4, 5, 4]}
)
```

```
def compute_vif(df)
    df = df.select_dtypes(include='number').apply(pd.to_numeric)
    features = df.columns.to_list()
    vif_data = pd.DataFrame()
    vif_data['feature'] = features
    vif_data['VIF'] = [variance_inflation_factor(df.values, i) for i in range(df.shape[1])]

    return vif_data.sort_values(by=['VIF'], ascending=False)

vif_data = compute_vif(df)
```

```
multicollinearity = True

while multicollinearity:
    highest_vif_feature = vif_data['feature'].values[-1]
    print('Removing: ', highest_vif_feature)
    df = df.drop(highest_vif_feature, axis=1)
    vif_data = compute_vif(df)
    multicollinearity = False if vif_data['VIF'].iloc[1] > 100 else True
```

How can I fix the last line of the while loop to address this?